# how does dynamic linker resolve references while the application is running?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

let's say I have a source file `dll.c` that use `dlopen` and `dlsym` functions to load a shared library called `F.so` in run time.

`dll.c` has a reference to `some_function()`, and `F.so` has the definition of `some_function()`.

and let's say the picture below is the executable object `prog` which is obtained by

```
linux> gcc -rdynamic -o prog dll.c -ldl
```

[image]

so `.text` section contains the reference of `some_function()` that needs to be resolved when the porgram load `F.so` and start to call `some_function()`

My questions are:

Q1-it seems to me that the `.text` section(where `some_function()` belongs to) in RAM(executable is copied into memory) needs to be modified by the dynamic linker so that the reference of `some_function()` can be resolved, is my understanding correct?

Q2-If the  dynamic linker needs to modify the `.text` section in RAM, how does it do it? from my understanding, `.text` section is read-only segment in RAM, how can a read-only segment be modified if it is called read-only?

Comment: Every _module_ (main executable and shared object) has its own data and code segments. The code-segments can be shared between processes, as they are read-only. (Also the code-segments of shared objects have to be position-independent.) The inter-module function calls are implemented via adapter-functions (aka 'glue code') and special data-areas.

Comment: Multiply posted at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/607551/5132 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1 - it seems to me that the .text section (where some_function() belongs to) in RAM(executable is copied into memory) needs to be modified by the dynamic linker ...

No. The actual code uses an indirect jump:

```
.text
    ...
    call *xsome_function
    ...

.data
xsome_function:
    .long some_function
```

... so the `call` instruction will not jump to a certain address, but it will jump to some address which is stored in the `.data` section. The dynamic linker must replace the address in the line `.long some_function`, not the address in the `call` instruction.

If you link code that contains a "direct" `call` instruction, the linker will do what JCWasmx86 wrote in his answer:

```
.text
    ...
    call some_function@PLT
    ...
some_function@PLT:
    jmp *xsome_function

.data
xsome_function:
    .long some_function
```

And once again the dynamic linker only has to replace the address in the `.data` section.

> `dlopen`

If you use `dlopen` and `dlsym` to access your library, the dynamic linker does not even replace anything:

`dlsym()` returns some function pointer which is handled like any other pointer that is returned by some other function (like a pointer returned by `malloc()`). The program calling `dlsym()` is responsible for storing the pointer somehow.

When calling a function using a function pointer, the compiler will always create an indirect jump instruction (such as `call %eax`).

> Q2 - If the dynamic linker needs to modify the .text section in RAM, ...

Years ago I wrote some small compiler/linker for Linux.

Because I came from Windows development and Window's dynamic linker actually replaces addresses in the `.text` section, I wrote my compiler/linker the same way I would have done it under Windows:

The result: The dynamic linker (`ld-linux.so`) simply crashed when running a program compiled using my compiler causing a "segmentation fault" because the dynamic linker cannot write to the `.text` segment under Linux.

**--Edit--**

An example:

If `dlopen()` and `dlsym()` are used, the C code does not look like this:

```
extern double sin(double x);
...
sine = sin(angle);
```

Instead, the C code looks like this:

```
static double (*psin)(double x);
...
sofile = dlopen("libm.so",FLAGS);
psin = dlsym(sofile,"sin");
...
sine = psin(angle);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.   by the way, you mentioned If use dlopen and dlsym to access your library, the dynamic linker does not even replace `.data` section, since dlsym() returns some function pointer and calling a function by function pointer actually make Program Counter directly " jumps" to `.text` section of the shared library , is my understand correct?

Comment: @slowjams Your understanding is correct. A "function pointer" is a variable containing the address of a function. Another typical use case for function pointers is passing a function that shall be called by another function as function argument (for example to `qsort()`). Calling that function does not require modifying the code. I'll add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1-it seems to me that the .text section(where some_function() belongs to) in RAM(executable is copied into memory) needs to be modified by the dynamic linker so that the reference of some_function() can be resolved, is my understanding correct?

It doesn't have to be like that. There is PLT (Procedure linkage table). It is essentially like this:

```
foo@PLT:
        jmp <someTemporaryAddress>
main:
        call foo@PLT
```

And then, while runtime, the dynamic linker only patches this section, because it is more simpler than finding calls in a lot of machine code.

> Q2-If the dynamic linker needs to modify the .text section in RAM, how does it do it? from my understanding, .text section is read-only segment in RAM, how can a read-only segment be modified if it is called read-only?

It's done before making it executable/read-only.